# <figcaption> not displaying

Tags: html, css

I would like to know why is my figcaption not displaying

I'm doing the usual code:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fimmv%C3%B6r%C3%B0uh%C3%A1ls" 
            target="_blank" class="grid-box">

            <img class="grid-img" 
            src="https://www.extremeiceland.is/media/8354/lava.jpg" 
            alt="Fimmvörðuháls">

            <figcaption>Fimmvörðuháls</figcaption>
 </a>
```

A screenshot: http://prntscr.com/kfinwm

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/don0ts/pen/ajayZE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are wrapped in an `<a>` tag, which has the class `.grid-box` which in turn, has its overflow set to hidden.
Try to remove `overflow: hidden` from `.grid-box`.